# How to get specific column from model in Django?

Tags: django

How to get specific column from model in Django( SELECT city FROM advert ) and how to display the city repeated only once?(I have London x3)

My model:

```
class Advert(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    company = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try

```
Advert.objects.values('city').distinct()
```

Or

```
Advert.objects.values_list('city', flat=True).distinct()
```

Also, Checking [the doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/) is a must to take advantage of Django ORM QuerySet.